# SqlDataReader invalid attempt to read when no data is present

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using this code for exporting data from SQL Server to a text file. But I get this error message in the line:

```
sw.WriteLine(read["Total"].ToString());
```

after

```
while(read.Read())
```

Code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select i.Name,i.Quantity,i.Price, (Select Sum(Quantity*Price) from InventorytransTemp where TableName=(Select top 1 TableName from InventorytransTemp)  and PrintFiscal=1)as Total ,j.MainGroupItemCode from InventorytransTemp i join InventoryMainGroupitems j on i.CategoryID=j.MainGroupItemID where TableName=(Select top 1 TableName from InventorytransTemp)  and PrintFiscal=1 ", con);

SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\fiscal.txt"))
{
    while (read.Read())
    {
        sw.Write("S/");
        string tempString = (read["Name"].ToString());

        if (tempString.Length > 20)
            tempString = tempString.Substring(0, 20);
        else
        {
            tempString = tempString.PadRight(20);
            tempString = tempString.PadLeft(0);
        }

        sw.Write(tempString + "/");
        String.Format("{0:0.000}", 0.5);
        sw.Write("  ");
        sw.Write(String.Format("{0:0.000}", double.Parse(read["Quantity"].ToString())).Replace(",", ".") + "/");
        sw.Write("   ");
        sw.Write(String.Format("{0:0.00}", double.Parse(read["Price"].ToString())).Replace(",", ".") + "/");
        sw.Write("      99/");
        sw.Write(" " + read["MainGroupItemCode"].ToString() + "/");

        sw.WriteLine();
    }

    sw.WriteLine(read["Total"].ToString());//I get error  in this line invalid attempt to read when no data is present

    sw.Close();
    read.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: The `while` loop advances the reader all the way to the end. There is nothing more to read after the loop.

Comment: So put `sw.WriteLine(read["Total"].ToString());`.inside the while loop, perhaps with an if statement so Total is only written out once.

Comment: what is the error msg you are getting ?

Comment: Why read to close after loop. read closes when i will use read.Close(); Until Then read should be open for each my action.Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I just used a string for taking my value in loop and then i use it after my read.

```
  String Total;

  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\fiscal.txt"))
            {
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    sw.Write("S/");
                    string tempString = (read["Name"].ToString());
                    if (tempString.Length > 20)
                        tempString = tempString.Substring(0, 20);
                    else
                    {
                        tempString = tempString.PadRight(20);
                        tempString = tempString.PadLeft(0);
                    }
                    sw.Write(tempString + "/");
                    String.Format("{0:0.000}", 0.5);
                    sw.Write("  ");
                    sw.Write(String.Format("{0:0.000}", double.Parse(read["Quantity"].ToString())).Replace(",", ".") + "/");
                    sw.Write("   ");
                    sw.Write(String.Format("{0:0.00}", double.Parse(read["Price"].ToString())).Replace(",", ".") + "/");
                    sw.Write("      99/");
                    sw.Write(" " + read["MainGroupItemCode"].ToString() + "/");
                    sw.WriteLine();
                    Total = ("CR/  " + String.Format("{0:0.00}", double.Parse(read["Total"].ToString())).Replace(",", "."));

                }
                sw.WriteLine(Total);
                sw.Close();
                read.Close();
```